# Android change Fragment page

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-xml, android-tabactivity

[you can download my zip here](http://androidfrag.site88.net/)

ok so i made an app with Swipe+Tab View i want each tab to show a diffrent .xml page if u click above you can download my workspace to edit it .. i really need help please be spicific to if u want i can setup teamviwer if it could be faster.. if u dont want to download the file cause u think "it has a virus" just make a reply down below here is my code for the mainactivity.java

```
package twh.reviser.root;

import java.util.Locale;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.Int2;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container,    false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What is not working actually?

Comment: @Greensy sorry if i made that un clear, so i have 3 tabs t1 t2 t3 when im on t1 i want it to show a new xml page and t2 same thing so im having problems making the xml change when it goes to a new tab.. any ideas or help?

Comment: like each section or tab should be diffrent and shwo diffrent things like in tab 1 it should have a button tab2 text tab 3 an image but how do i make that show diffrent activitys or fragments ??

Comment: @JacobAnthonyTonna, put your code in the link again. I'll try to check it.

Comment: my webhost got mad abut having that up

Comment: @Jacob Anthony Tonna what you want exactly?viewPager + swipeTabs?no teamViewer but i can post some code with understanding if you want..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of my adapter that solves your problem. TabsPagerAdapter is just separate class.

```
/**
 * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
 * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost.  It relies on a
 * trick.  Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
 * Intent that each tab will show.  This is not sufficient for switching
 * between pages.  So instead we make the content part of the tab host
 * 0dp high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy
 * view to show as the tab content.  It listens to changes in tabs, and takes
 * care of switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected
 * tab changes.
 */
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final OnPageChangeListener mListener;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;






    static final class TabInfo {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public void addTab(String label, String tag, Drawable drawable, Class<?> c, int resourse) {
        addTab(this.mContext, label, tag, drawable, c, resourse);
    }

    public void addTab(Context context, String label, String tag, Drawable drawable, Class<?> c, int resourse) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag);

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resourse, (TabWidget)mTabHost.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs), false);

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        this.addTab(spec, c, null);
    }

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager, OnPageChangeListener listener, FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        mFragmentManager = manager;
        mContext = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mListener = listener;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position){

    }



    public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
        return getFragmentAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
    }

    public Fragment getFragmentAt(int position){
        return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":" + position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = (TabInfo) mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        //called when the user clicks on a tab.
        int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != position){
             mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
         if(mListener!=null){
             mListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
        // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
        // The jerk.
        // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
        // ViewPager.
        TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        if(mListener!=null){
            mListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
         if(mListener!=null){
             mListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
         }
    }
}
```

This is android example framentadapter with tiny modifications.

Example usage
MainActivity.java

```
class MainActivity extends FragmentActivuty{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mTabsAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager,null, getSupportFragmentManager());

    mTabsAdapter.addTab("Button", "button",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawable),
    ButtonFragment.class, R.layout.yourtablayout);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab("Text","text",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawable), TextFragment.class, R.layout.yourtablayout);


    //This is needed so your tabs do not reload each time
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mTabsAdapter.getCount());

}
```

Comment: im still confused so do i add this to my MainActivity.java or do i replace MainActivity.java with this

Comment: i think iv figured this out... Greensy if i cant figure it out would u be willing to teamview with me?

Comment: I can add additionl comments here, do not think it is good idea to share conta cts on public site

Comment: i have been trying for hours now... do u think u can download my zip and edit the code to make it work please?

Comment: its not that i just dont understand how to do it.. but i got a friend to help me  so its all good .. if some one can help me make my actionbar like the IOS actionbar ill give u the 50 points

Answer (score 0):

I integrated some code that I wrote with the code you provided. I think this should work, based upon you having used the generic Android ADT setup.

```
package twh.reviser.root;

import java.util.Locale;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.Int2;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    /** possibly missing from your code*/
        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        Context c;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context c,FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            this.c = c;         
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            if (position == 0) {

                fragment = new FragmentPage1(c);

                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                }

            if (position == 1) {

                fragment = new FragmentPage2(c);

                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                }
            if (position == 2) {

                fragment = new FragmentPage3(c);

                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container,    false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

## Create three xml files for each of the three fragments in res/layout/

Fragment_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment_3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## Create three java files for the three fragments in src/twh.reviser.root

FragmentPage1.java

```
package twh.reviser.root;

public class FragmentPage1 extends Fragment  {

    Context c;

    public FragmentInputPage1(){
    }

    public FragmentInputPage1(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Fragment_1, null);

        return v;

    }
}
```

FragmentPage2.java

```
package twh.reviser.root;

public class FragmentPage2 extends Fragment  {

    Context c;

    public FragmentInputPage2(){
    }

    public FragmentInputPage2(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Fragment_2, null);

        return v;

    }
}
```

FragmentPage3.java

```
package twh.reviser.root;

public class FragmentPage3 extends Fragment  {

    Context c;

    public FragmentInputPage3(){
    }

    public FragmentInputPage3(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Fragment_3, null);

        return v;

    }
}
```

If you want to get the value of an id from another fragment you can use the below, based upon FragmentPage1 having the following public variables declared

```
public static String a,b,c;
```

Within FragmentPage1.java

```
public class FragmentPage3 extends Fragment  {

Context c;

String a = "";
String b = "";
String c = "";

@Override    
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Fragment_3, null);

    a = FragmentPage1.a;
    b = FragmentPage1.b;
    c = FragmentPage1.c;
```